# When I try to use easy_install, it shows can't decompress data; zlib not available

Tags: python, centos, zlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Python-2.7 on Ubuntu 10.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047212/installing-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-10-4)

I am using CentOS, which bundled with python 2.4. But python 2.4 didn't come with a lot of new features so I downloaded source of 2.7.

After ./configure, make, make install, when I try to install setuptools or easy_install, it shows "zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available".

I checked my zlib installions:

```
zlib.i386                                1.2.3-3                       installed
zlib-devel.i386                          1.2.3-4.el5                   installed
```

And yes, I aslo edited the Modules/Setup file under python source, uncomment the zlib line to make sure zlib includes.

But none of them works. The zlib in python still missing.
Please help me.

Comment: You might want to check out this answer: 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946413/interesting-problem-with-python-2-7-on-centos-is-this-an-issue-with-my-build

Comment: I am compiling with shared enabled, and there is only 1 python2.7 in the system. The default python is 2.7. So the post didn't help, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow I found a workaround.

I noticed the output of make/make install, it did output the zlibmodule.o in the ./Modules directory, but for some reason it did not link the zlibmodule.o into a zlibmodule.so and copy it into lib directory.

So I run gcc for myself, get the zlibmodule.so and copied it into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/, everything works fine now.

But still, this is a workaround. I will be glad if anyone could point out the real reason.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution!!